# Got "A block with a higher watermark than the current one was previously baked" Error when creating a private chain

Tags: baking, private

I'm new to Tezos and I'm deploying a private network by following the [private-tezos-blockchain](https://github.com/serokell/private-tezos-blockchain) demo project, but with a more recent version of tezos binary (v14.1-1) and protocol.

I've succeeded deploying nodes and activating the protocol **PtKathmankSp** at level 1. Then the baker instances (and `tezos-client bake for my-baker`) got this error message:

```
Oct 18 10:54:32.003 - 014-PtKathma.baker.actions: Voting pass for liquidity baking toggle vote
Oct 18 10:54:32.012 - 014-PtKathma.baker.actions: potential double baking detected at level 2, round 5
Error:
  A block with a higher watermark than the current one (level: 2, round: 5) was previously baked.
```

And here is the logging messages from the node:

```
Oct 18 10:54:00.221 - node.main: the Tezos node is now running
Oct 18 10:54:02.364 - p2p.maintenance: too few connections (0)
Oct 18 10:54:16.181 - validation: initializing protocol PtKathmankSp...
Oct 18 10:54:16.182 - validator.block: block at level 1 successfully pre-applied
Oct 18 10:54:16.182 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2022-10-18T08:54:16.178-00:00, treated in 9.5us, completed in 3.157ms 
Oct 18 10:54:16.186 - validator.block: block BM8TSncvUGyQ3rHDsfSD7y5R95G4w7WdogYwTF9Nn6voPca15e1 successfully validated
Oct 18 10:54:16.186 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2022-10-18T08:54:16.184-00:00, treated in 9.34us, completed in 1.61ms 
Oct 18 10:54:16.186 - validator.chain: Sync_status: sync
Oct 18 10:54:16.186 - node.chain_validator: no prevalidator filter found for protocol
Oct 18 10:54:16.186 - node.chain_validator:   Ps9mPmXaRzmzk35gbAYNCAw6UXdE2qoABTHbN2oEEc1qM7CwT9P
Oct 18 10:54:16.186 - validator.chain: Chain is bootstrapped
Oct 18 10:54:16.187 - node.store: the protocol table was updated: protocol PtKathmankSp (level 1) was activated
Oct 18 10:54:16.187 - node.store:   on block BM8TSncvUGyQ3rHDsfSD7y5R95G4w7WdogYwTF9Nn6voPca15e1 (level 1)
Oct 18 10:54:16.189 - validator.chain: Update current head to BM8TSncvUGyQ3rHDsfSD7y5R95G4w7WdogYwTF9Nn6voPca15e1 (level 1, timestamp 2022-10-18T08:54:16-00:00, fitness 00::0000000000000019), same branch
Oct 18 10:54:16.189 - validator.chain: Request pushed on 2022-10-18T08:54:16.185-00:00, treated in 373us, completed in 2.192ms 
Oct 18 10:54:32.011 - validator.block: block at level 2 successfully pre-applied
Oct 18 10:54:32.011 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2022-10-18T08:54:32.005-00:00, treated in 29.341us, completed in 6.94ms
```

Anyone has an idea on where the problem is? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you made several tries, and you forgot to wipe all baking data? The baker (via `tezos-client bake for` in your messages) saves some info about last baked block's level and fitness as a security against double-baking. If you don't remove those files, the baker may refuse to produce blocks for levels it thinks they are in the past.